# Задать размер миниатюр в галлерее ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, gallery, acf

Использую Advanced Custom Fields. Это код который выводит галлерею.

```
           <div class="slider-1_wrapp" id="slider1">

                <?php 

                $images = get_field('slider_1_gallery');

                if( $images ): ?>
                    <div class="big_slider">
                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="miniature_slider">
                        <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                            <div class="slide">
                                <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" class="miniature" data-fancybox = "1">
                                    <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
                                    <div class="mask">
                                        <i class="icon_1"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>                              
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
```

Как в строке

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
```

задать размер миниатюр? Нужно их уменьшать и обрезать по макету при загрузке изображений разных размеров.

Answer (score 0):

В Настройках->Медиафайлы можно задать нужный размер миниатюры. "Из коробки" доступны thumbnail (в вашем коде), medium, large. Соответственно, ваш код для medium будет выглядеть так:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['thumbnail']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
```

Если нужен другой размер, его можно задать через `add_image_size()`.

```
add_image_size( 'my-gallery', $width, $height, $crop );
```

В коде тогда так:

```
<img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['my-gallery']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
```

Подробнее [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_image_size).

Comment: Делаю так                                                                                                                         if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
  add_image_size( 'gallery-thumbnails', 165, 110, false );
 }                            в коде тогда так                                                                 <img src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['gallery-thumbnails']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />                                                                               
не работает

Comment: Где "делаете так"? Что значит - "не работет"? "Не работает" - худшее определение проблемы, какое только может быть. Думай, что хочешь - монитор взрывается, сайт падает, ничего не выводится вместо картинки, выводится картинка другого размера. Опишите проблему подробно.